# Chrome Extension - get tab ID in sidePanel?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Ive been using message passing in my Chrome Extension to get the tab ID in my UI.

The content script injects an iframe which loads a React app. React sends a message:

```
const tabId = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  message: MSG_GET_TAB_ID,
});
```

Which the background script responds to:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  const { message } = request;
  const tabId = sender?.tab?.id;
  if (tabId === undefined) return;

  if (message === MSG_GET_TAB_ID) {
    sendResponse(tabId);
  }
});
```

If I log out the results of `tabId` I can see its worked.

However now I want to use the sidePanel:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/#type-PanelOptions

I've removed the code to inject the iframe via the content script and instead just add this to the manifest.json (storage was already there):

```
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "sidePanel"
  ],
    "side_panel": {
        "default_path": "./src/ui/popup.html"
    },
```

If I open the side panel in Chrome and choose my app I can see that React is rendering correctly, however `tabId` is `undefined`.

From logging out the `sender` object in the background script I can see the object has `id`, `url` and `origin` but no longer has `tab` which had `id`. So it seems the message listener doesn't know which tab the side panel was opened on.

Is there a way to get message passing working as before or another way of finding out the tab id from within the side panels context?

Comment: Try doing it inside the panel: `await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})` and in case it doesn't handle multi-window browser replace the last parameter with `windowId: (await chrome.windows.getCurrent()).id`

Comment: @wOxxOm using await chrome.tabs.query does seem to work. Do you know if this will always return the correct ID? Im concerned there could be edge cases if you had multiple tabs / windows open. Im surprised a best practice approach isnt part of the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is happening as the sidePanel is in the same context as the background script, so message passing doesn't work between the 2.

As wOxxOm said in the comments using `chrome.tabs.query` works.