# Chrome Extension: How to show the active tab URL (with updates when it changes) in a sidePanel?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

For Chrome Extensions, how can you show the active tab URL in a sidePanel and have it update when it changes?

I found a way to get the initial active tab.  But I need it to update when the tab changes.

I tried the suggestion in comments in [Chrome Extension - get tab ID in sidePanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456744/chrome-extension-get-tab-id-in-sidepanel) but that didn't work.

I want to be able to use this to enable/disable some buttons in the side panel depending on the URL of the active tab.

I saw this about Enabling the side panel for a specific site (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/#by-site) but that doesn't actually work. A user would have to manually reopen the side panel. (See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/issues/982)

=== Additional info ====

In comments it was suggested I use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.  I've tried that unsuccessfully, which is why I'm asking.

I tried this in sidepanel.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  console.log("-----", tabId, changeInfo, tab);
});
```

but if I switch to another tab it doesn't get called.  It does get called if I change the URL in the active tab.

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated event.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried.  I added more info to the question.  Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener looks somewhat promising. It is called when a open a new tab, change the url, and switch tabs.  However, when switching tabs the callback function's first arg as tabId and windowId only and the other args are undefined.  Can I get more information about the tab from the windowId and tabId ??

Comment: Add `tabs` to permissions.

Comment: I was mistaken about chrome.tabs.onActivated.  If a url is changed within the active tab it is not fired.
Maybe I need to use a combination of chrome.tabs.onActivated in sidepanel and chrome.tabs.onUpdated in service-worker with it passing info to the sidepanel.  That seems ugly.  I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: @wOxxOm It has tabs permission

Comment: Using onActivated + onUpdated is the only method. You can do it inside the side panel. To get the info for onActivated use chrome.tabs.get with the provided tab id.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks!  I'm not sure why onUpdated wasn't working before in sidepanel but I'm getting it to work now.  The combination of the 2 while checking to make sure active is true seems to do it.  I'll post an answer, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a combination of onActivated and onUpdated.  The onActivated will be called when the user changes tabs.  The onUpdated is called when a tab URL is changed.
Since onUpdated can be called on a no longer active tab (e.g. type the URL for a slow loading site that will change then go to another tab) also check that the tab is active.

Put this code in the sidepanel and create a setActiveURL to handle the URL changes.

```
/* Set for initial active tab when open the sidepanel */
(async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
  setActiveURL(tab.url);
})();

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(async (activeInfo) => {
  const tab = await chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId);
  if (tab.active) {
    console.log("======= active tab url", tab.url);
    setActiveURL(tab.url);
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (tab.active) {
    console.log("======= active tab url", tab.url);
    setActiveURL(tab.url);
  }
});
```